# How to make relationship between three table in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables, Sections,Questions and options.
Each Section has many questions and each question has many options.
How  can I fetch data from this tables related to each other?

Section model relationship with Question model

```
      class Section extends Model
      {
      use HasFactory;
      protected $primaryKey='sectionid';
       public function questions(){
       return $this->hasMany(Question::class,'sectionid')->orderBy('order');
     }
   }
```

Question model relationship with Option model:

```
class Question extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;
   protected $primaryKey='questionid';
   public $timestamps = true;
   public function options(){
     return $this->hasMany(Option::class,'questionid');
  }
}
```

my query:

```
            $data=Section::with('questions')
                            ->where('formid',$formId)
                            ->orderBy('sectionid')
                            ->get()
                            ->toJson();
```

It returns this:
[image: output]

I want each questions member contains options array related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested relation in with like below.So it will fetch question options also

```
 $data=Section::with(['questions','questions.options'])
                            ->where('formid',$formId)
                            ->orderBy('sectionid')
                            ->get()
                            ->toJson();
```

Comment: @HamHp.if its helpful then please accept answer as accepted

Comment: I will do it @John Lobo in 1 minute

Comment: @JohnLobo you don't need to add both `'questions','questions.options'`. `questions.options` relation will have `questions` relation also

Comment: @Haridarshan.yes you are right .Its also possible